# Adding tenant id and user id to ad hoc cache

Tags: jasperserver

We have the adhoc cache enabled, but we are using a custom query executer to retrieve the data. For jasperserver it looks like it's using one datasource while instead it could be a different one then before.

We have a multitenancy setup for jasperserver (4.7)0.

In this we have a couple of adhoc views wich are the same for every tenant and user. We have a custom query executer wich makes sure the report is run on the right database etc.

But when we turn on the adhoc cache, it will cache results for a certain adhoc view. To prevent other users from seeing the wrong data (from the cache) we would like to add the tenantId and the UserId to the adhoc cache key, or maybe insert that parameter from within the custom query executer.

Does anybody know if this is possible ?

Greetings,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing is, is to create your own version of the DefaultCacheKeyInterceptor, and add a User object (even if there is none specified in the report).

Then edit the applicationContext-datarator.xml, and change the class entry of the keyInterceptor bean definition to your own class.